# iterm2 issue : create new tab with same path of previous current tab BUT 2 tabs are clones and not indepedent

Tags: terminal, keyboard, mojave, shortcut, iterm

**You can see the bounty launched on StackOverflow ([Bounty started about ìTerm2 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58502166/iterm2-issue-create-new-tab-with-same-path-of-previous-current-tab-but-2-tabs)) about this issue described below.**

I have switched from default terminal on MacOSs Mojave to `iterm2`. I have an issue about the opening of a new tab from the current tab.

Indeed, I would like to be in the same path than the previous current tab.

For this, I did the classical procedure, i.e to go to `iterm2` preferences and `Profile` and choose `Reuse previous session's directory` for new tab :

[image]

**Then, the issue is that once tab opened, all the other tabs are affected and change from their old path to the path of the new tab** :  I don't understand what happens and which option to use to  prevent this behavior ?

**1) Evevery tab is the same than the others : if I do a `cd ~/foo/`, then the other tabs will go into `foo`directory.**

**2) Result worse : if I edit with `vim` a file in one tab, if I do a `cd ~/foo/` in another tab, then the tab associated to the edited file disappears is clearing this edition and shows the same windows than the tab where I did `cd ~/foo/` : Very strange ...**

I want to keep all the current path  for all  others tabs except for the new one which must be the  same than the previous one from which I do a CMD+T.

Has anyone met this kind of issue ? I saw on different forums this issue sometimes occurs.

**UPDATE 1:**

From what I have seen, it seems that I hvave to find a way to create a new session when I do the shortcut CMD+T to get another tab independent from the current one (from which I do CMD+T).

But unfortunately, I didn't find how to create a new session in `iTerm2` (inside the `iTerm2 - Preferences - profile`, I could execute a script that creates this new session). From the moment, you can see the command (`/bin/bash` that I launch when I open a new tab :

[image: command /bin/bash launched for new tab]

I tried also to build the binary `iTerm2` from the sources but issue remains.

**UPDATE 2:** I tried to use a little apple script to force a new session to be created from current window :

```
tell application "iTerm2"
    tell current window
        create tab with profile "Terminology2"
    end tell
end tell
```

where Terminology2 is a duplicate of profile Terminology (default profile).

But always the same issue, the 2 tabs are not independent : each command in one of 2 is executed on the another one.

**UPDATE 2:** **Solution finally fixed** on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58502166/iterm2-issue-create-new-tab-with-same-path-of-previous-current-tab-but-2-tabs)

Comment: Could anyone have clues or suggestions to get independent tabs by opening a new tab with CMD+T on Catalina MacOS on a 2019 MacBook pro ? Regards